# Class Security by User Profile

Tags: trigger

If a handler class is invoked from a trigger but the class is not shared with the profile (Class Security), will the class method get invoked?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? What was your outcome? I have seen that if you don't have access of VF page you can't see it, i am not sure about class though.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I am not sure. I got a mixed outcome. When I tried with System Admin the method was not invoked. But from other profile the method was invoked. I doubt I missed something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apex Class Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_package_security.htm&type=0):

> These permissions apply only to Apex class methods. The method can be a web service method or any method used in a custom Visualforce controller or controller extension that’s applied to a Visualforce page. *In contrast, triggers always fire on trigger events (such as insert or update), regardless of a user’s permissions.*

---

I wrote a series of triggers and classes, posted below. None of the users in the testing org have permissions to run the class used in the trigger, and I used the `with sharing` keywords to ensure apex sharing rules were enforced.

Each time the class is called, it logs the user id of the user who made the call, and a `system.assert` is used to ensure the call was made.

I ran this in a test class, and it called for each user in the list.

## Trigger

```
trigger TestingTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    TestingPermissionsClass.RunSomething();
}
```

## Class

```
public with sharing class TestingPermissionsClass {

    @testVisible 
    private static Map<Id, Boolean> calledBy { 
        get {
            if (calledBy == null) {
                calledBy = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
            }

            return calledBy; 
        } 
        set;
    }

    public static void RunSomething() {
        System.debug('Class was run by user: ' + UserInfo.getName());
        calledBy.put(UserInfo.getUserId(), true);
    }

}
```

## Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestingPermissions_test {

    @isTest
    public static void Test() {
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name != 'System Administrator' AND IsActive = true LIMIT 15];
        Account a = Generate.CreateAccount(); 

        for (User u:users) {
            System.runAs(u) {
                a.Id = null; 

                insert a;
            }

            System.assert(TestingPermissionsClass.calledBy.get(u.Id));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi BatteryCord. Do you mean any class called from trigger will be called based on user's access to trigger  irrespective of the class is shared with the profile or not?

Comment: I think it means that just the trigger itself will be run, even if you haven't explicitly shared the trigger with the user who's running it.  I'm digging around for a more specific example currently

Comment: I just wrote a test and an example class, and it looks like the class was called in each instance of users, even though I didn't provide permissions to the class to the users. I'm going to run another test before I edit my answer, but it looks like it runs regardless.